# Como criar uma lista de valores com restrição em relação à um número de dados estipulado

Tags: r, lista

Tenho o seguinte código

```
n <- 130  
pl <- trunc(n/20)
p0 <- 20
pp <- 20 + (0:(pl-1))*p0
```

Com o resultado de `pp`, sendo: `[1]  20  40  60  80 100 120`. Além disso, também uso o mesmo processo para a criação de um `pe`, de acordo com o seguinte código:

```
pe <- c(1:8)
for(i in 1:6){
  pe[i] <- pl*20+i*20}
pe[7] <- pe[6]+100
pe[8] <- pe[7]+100
```

Da mesma forma, o resultado de `pe`é:  `[1] 140 160 180 200 220 240 340 440`.

Os códigos acima são utilizados para calcular valores que serão considerados para determinar a quantidade de observações extraídas de um arquivo de dados que possui 485 observações. No entanto, tenho outro arquivo que possui apenas 199 observações originais e preciso criar um looping que crie essa lista, mas com as seguintes restrições: Os valores resultantes de pe não devem passar da quantidade de observações no arquivo, definida no meu algoritmo como: `(nrow(dados_original))` e, de preferência as variáveis devem conter 5 valores com intervalo de 20 unidades entre eles. No caso das 199 observações, ficaria apenas (140,160,180). No caso de 350 observações ficaria (140,160,180,200,220,320). Obrigado pelas sugestões.

Comment: Diz que as variáveis devem conter 5 valores mas no caso de 350 observações `(140,160,180,200,220,320)` tem 6 valores. É erro?

Answer (score 3):

Veja se a seguinte função é o que quer. Os resultados estão de acordo com os resultados esperados da pergunta.

```
valores <- function(obs, n = 130, incr = 20, incr2 = 100, comprimento = 5){
  pl <- trunc(n/incr)
  res <- seq(pl*incr + incr, obs, by = incr)
  if(length(res) > comprimento){
    res <- res[seq_len(comprimento)]
    res <- c(res, seq(res[comprimento] + incr2, obs, by = incr2))
  }
  res
}

valores(199)
#[1] 140 160 180

valores(350)
#[1] 140 160 180 200 220 320
```

Comment: Sua função apresenta um erro para valores entre 240 e 310. Alguns arquivos possuem observações entre esses valores. Algum problema com o incr2 eu acho.